# Update Row=Row - 1 set the row to 0

Tags: php

I am trying to take 1 or add 1 to the row like so:

```
$updatequality = $database->prepare("UPDATE products SET quantity=quantity - 1 AND purchases=purchases + 1 WHERE id=?");
```

but quantity, and purchases go to 0 on each query. I am not sure why

Comment: Is the "AND" right? Shouldn't that be a comma? I'd have thought it would be a syntax error, but maybe it is evaluating the RHS as a Boolean false (or zero)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the proper mysql `UPDATE` syntax, because it is `,` not the `AND` when you want to update multiple columns. see more here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

```
UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col2 - 1;
                            ^^^
```

For your query,

```
$updatequality = $database->prepare("UPDATE products SET quantity=quantity - 1 , purchases=purchases + 1 WHERE id=?");
```